# Is it possible to play video on the notification panel of android?

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

On sending **push notification** via fcm messages (a video link specifically), on touch could it be **played on notification panel directly** only rather than inapp. Is it possible to play a video on notification panel on android.

Comment: I have in mind that something like that was introduced as new feature in Android 11.

Comment: Do you have any idea how can this be done?